# redux-saga combine fork with race

Tags: redux, redux-saga

Is there a way to combine `fork` with `race` in redux-saga? For example something like this?

[image]

**What I want to achieve:** I want to fetch without blocking the UI, so I can react to certain dispatched user actions, such as `SELECT_TAB_XYZ` and immediately switch the tab but keep fetching in the background. I guess by default dispatched actions are cached (if I do `response: call(request, requestURL),`).

Comment: Please explain more about why dispatched actions are cached. IMO, saga will run in background by default.

Comment: I would fork new saga and put the race using call and delay there. Having the delay in the top saga doesn't make sense because that would block the execution of the top saga as well.